# URL doesn't exist in REST api call

Tags: apex, rest, platform-event

[image]

I'm trying to subscribing platform event channel through REST. I have executed below code I'm getting the error called 
"URL doesn't exist".

Is there any changes needed in the url format. Please suggest

```
public class ConsumePlatformEventsChannel {
public static HttpResponse makeGetCallout() {

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://sfpractice1-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/event/Order_Event__e');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    System.debug('Response:::'+response.getBody());

    return response;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`event/Order_Event__e` is the channel name, but it's not the complete URL endpoint. Per [Subscribe to Platform Event Notifications with CometD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_cometd.htm), you need to prefix the channel name with the CometD endpoint:

> Use this CometD endpoint with the API version appended to it.

```
/cometd/47.0
```

Regardless, making a REST callout is not how you subscribe to a Platform Events channel. Platform Events (and other long polling products, like the Streaming API) require implementing a CometD client that receives events over a long-lived HTTP connection (among other facets of the protocol).

Use one of the existing features to [subscribe to Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe.htm), such as an Apex trigger, or the Lightning `empApi` component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I'm trying to publish events to an external system(AdobeConnect),Once the order record has updated in salesforce need to get the notification in Adobeconnect.1.I have created trigger on order object ,once the order has modified it publishes the platform events into a channel.I did this.

Comment: Step 2:How can I able to subscribe platform events in external system(AdobeConnect).So that I can get notification in my external system.

Comment: @Chandu There is detailed information about subscription options in the [Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe.htm). You will need to implement a Bayeux/CometD client on your remote system.

Comment: But consider using the newer Change Data Capture feature, which posts events for you.